# Pandastable add new column to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to use the `pandastable` library within my script. Basically the below script imports the user chosen `.csv` into a `pandastable` and displays correctly on `tkinter`GUI.

Once imported I would like to add columns. I assumed this would be easy enough using this doc *https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#basics* and its listed table methods. Eg: `table.autoAddColumns(1)` to add a single column(s), however no matter how i try and use it I cant get it to work..

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as tkrttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("2000x1000")
root.title('Workshop Manager')
style = tkrttk.Style()
style.configure("Treeview.Heading", foreground='Red', font=('Helvetica', 10))


def select_input_file():
    global input_file_path
    input_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
    filetypes=(("CSV files", "*.csv"),))
    app = TestApp(root, input_file_path)
    app.place(bordermode = INSIDE,height = 500, width = 2000, x =0, y=50)

class TestApp(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, input_file_path):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.table = Table(self, showtoolbar=False, showstatusbar=False)
        self.table.importCSV(input_file_path)
        self.table.show(input_file_path)
        ##Breaks here##
        self.table.autoAddColumns(1)

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried using `table.autoAddColumns(1)`. This didnt work either.

If I use `self.table.autoAddColumns(1)` I get error `AttributeError: 'TableModel' object has no attribute 'auto_AddColumns'`

If I use `table.autoAddColumns(1)` I get error `NameError: name 'table' is not defined`

Comment: It is a bug in `pandastable`.

Comment: ahh, thanks for the information. Maybe best to drop the pandastable library and stick with pandas.

Comment: You can use `addColumn()` function but it has a bug as well which can be fixed easily by patching the module source.

Comment: Thanks again for the info, I have never patched a module before, could you point me in the right direction to do this.. Cheers

Comment: Change the line `def addColumn(self, newname=None)` to `def addColumn(self, newname='None', dtype='object')` in `core.py` of `pandastable` module.  *Note that it will be overwritten if you upgrade the module and it only works in your Python environment*.  Or you can just call `self.table.addColumn()` without passing any argument, then you will be asked to select `dtype` and input the name of the new column.  In this case, you don't need to patch the source.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was allot easier to do than I thought and it works now using `self.table.addColumn`, Im quite new to SO but do you need to post as an answer? Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in `pandastable`.

However you can use `addColumn()` function instead.  When it is called without argument, a dialog will be shown to select the `dtype` and input the name of the new column.